# How can I let each dev have their own, private, web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config

Consider a bunch of developers working on an ASP.net web application. Each dev has a private copy of the DB, running on their private, local DB engine so each dev has a different connection string.

Currently, each dev has web.config modified with their connection string and occasionally one of these modifications gets committed to source control, which is not good.

How can I both have a default web.config in source control and let each dev have their own private copy that is ignored by source control? (I would prefer a solution that avoids web.config transformation files if possible, as their syntax is a bit opaque).

Comment: what source control are you using, and which version?

Comment: dont let them check in the web.config problem solved ;)

Comment: Why "with their connection string"? Have you tried to you use something like "localhost\DBName" (or whatever connection string you need for your DB) identical for everyone?

Comment: Its better to ensure the connectionstring is the same for all devs. `.` usually does the trick.

Comment: @JoshStevens: I once knew a developer with the same 'vision'. Mistakes where made a couple of times every month. ;-)

Comment: I know this is side-tracking a bit, but it worked well for me - I am using a config-setting wrapper that allow overriding the config values if it finds something in the ENV variables. So the web.config is actually with a dummy connection string, each dev sets their connstring once in their environment, and production sets a different one.

Comment: @Macb, SVN, soon migrating to git.

Comment: @JoshStevens Is that enforcible in SVN? Git? GitHub?

Comment: @Alexei-levelnkov @ stefan let's assume that's not possible. Team is distributed and ruly :)

Comment: @KenEgozi Care to share? :)

Comment: There you go: https://gist.github.com/kenegozi/13f49f755ca4b1225631

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that can help.

1. Enforce convention that is followed by all developers. For instance, Sql Server instance name, database name etc should be same on all developers machines so that you don't need to change them. Also any file location kind of settings should always be respective to the project or some system location. Overall the idea is to keep your settings so that developers need not checkout and change anything.
2. In some cases, enforcing the above might not be possible. In that scenario, you can move those changing settings to a different file and refer that in your web.config using 'configSource'. Then developers can change that settings file as per their local machine environment. Also in that case you would like to ensure that not everybody in the team can checkin that file so that to prevent unwanted overriding.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think `configSource=` will do the trick here. If I put the settings in an external file and never commit that file, then source control will be missing the settings and the app won't run when cloned. I'm looking for having a set of default config settings in source control that individual dev can override out of source control.

Comment: I think I did not clearly mention, you will check in the external setting file with the default values to the source control. But then restrict checkin of that file to only a few in the team.

Comment: Tx. Is it possible to limit check-in on a per user/group level for a file in SVN? What about git?

Answer (score 1):

In our projects I've set things up so that there the default configuration is under source control as `web.config.template` and the `web.config` itself is ignored. Developers then simply copy `web.config.template` as `web.config`; and make any local edits they need.

It's simple enough to be a manual thing, but it is also possible to use MSBuild to automate the copy (only copying if `web.config` doesn't already exist).

If you have a CI/build server then you may want to also take the approach that web.config.template contains the configuration for use in the CI build - that way your CI build is simplified as it can always just overwrite `web.config` with `web.config.template`.